# Decoding CalibrationL6.dll

Tags: dll, c#

I am having problems with a dll, it is called CalibrationL6.dll, I have been able to see the code inside, and the function that interests me is this:

```
public static int CalculateCoefficients(
          int[] coefficients,
          out int negCoeffs,
          int numPoints,
          int selCoeffs,
          int CalType,
          double[] bridgeRaw,
          double[] bridgeDesired,
          double[] tempRaw,
          double[] tempDesired)
        {
            CalData data = new CalData();
            Vector<CalPoint> calPoints = (Vector<CalPoint>)data.calPoints;
            LMCallbacks callbacks = new LMCallbacks();
            lm_control_type control = new lm_control_type();
            int index1 = 0;
            negCoeffs = 0;
            if (0 < numPoints)
            {
                do
                {
                    bridgeRaw[index1] = (double)Program.TwosComplementToDecimal((int)bridgeRaw[index1]);
                    tempRaw[index1] = (double)Program.TwosComplementToDecimal((int)tempRaw[index1]);
                    ++index1;
                }
                while (index1 < numPoints);
            }
            int index2 = 0;
            if (0 < numPoints)
            {
                do
                {
                    if (tempRaw != null && tempDesired != null)
                    {
                        CalPoint calPoint;
                        calPoint.rawB = bridgeRaw[index2];
                        calPoint.bridge = bridgeDesired[index2];
                        calPoint.temp = tempDesired[index2];
                        calPoint.rawT = tempRaw[index2];
                        calPoints.Add(calPoint);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CalPoint calPoint;
                        calPoint.rawB = bridgeRaw[index2];
                        calPoint.bridge = bridgeDesired[index2];
                        calPoint.temp = 2000.0;
                        calPoint.rawT = 2000.0;
                        calPoints.Add(calPoint);
                    }
                    ++index2;
                }
                while (index2 < numPoints);
            }
            data.CalType = CalType;
            data.CO_CAL = selCoeffs;
            Map<double, double> map = new Map<double, double>();
            List<CalPoint>.Enumerator enumerator1 = calPoints.GetEnumerator();
            if (enumerator1.MoveNext())
            {
                do
                {
                    CalPoint current = enumerator1.Current;
                    double key = Math.Truncate(current.temp * 10.0) / 10.0;
                    Dictionary<double, double>.Enumerator enumerator2 = map.GetEnumerator();
                    if (enumerator2.MoveNext())
                    {
                        while (Math.Abs(Map<double, double>.Key((ValueType)enumerator2.Current) - key) >= 0.1)
                        {
                            if (!enumerator2.MoveNext())
                                goto label_11;
                        }
                        goto label_12;
                    }
                label_11:
                    map[key] = current.rawT;
                label_12:;
                }
                while (enumerator1.MoveNext());
            }
            if (map.Size < 3)
                data.CO_CAL &= -561;
            if (map.Size < 2)
                data.CO_CAL &= -269;
            double[] par = new double[10];
            par[0] = 0.0;
            data.cos[0] = 0.0;
            data.cos[1] = 65536.0;
            data.cos[2] = 0.0;
            data.cos[3] = 0.0;
            data.cos[4] = 0.0;
            data.cos[5] = 0.0;
            data.cos[6] = 0.0;
            data.cos[7] = 0.0;
            data.cos[8] = 32768.0;
            data.cos[9] = 0.0;
            data.zero_point = 8388608.0;
            int[] numArray = new int[4] { 2, 4, 6, 7 };
            int num = 0;
            do
            {
                data.CalType = CalType;
                int index3 = 0;
                do
                {
                    int n_par = 0;
                    int index4 = 0;
                    if (0 < numArray[index3])
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            if ((data.CO_CAL >> index4 & 1) != 0)
                            {
                                par[n_par] = data.cos[index4];
                                ++n_par;
                            }
                            else
                                data.cos[index4] = (double)coefficients[index4];
                            ++index4;
                        }
                        while (index4 < numArray[index3]);
                    }
                    data.calcTo = numArray[index3];
                    control.Initialize();
                    //< Module >.lm_minimize(((Vector<CalPoint>)calPoints).Size, n_par, par, (ILMCallbacks)callbacks, (lm_data_type)data, control);
                    int index5 = 0;
                    int index6 = 0;
                    if (0 < numArray[index3])
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            if ((data.CO_CAL >> index6 & 1) != 0)
                            {
                                data.cos[index6] = par[index5];
                                ++index5;
                            }
                            ++index6;
                        }
                        while (index6 < numArray[index3]);
                    }
                    ++index3;
                }
                while (index3 < 4);
                data.CalType = 2;
                int n_par1 = 0;
                int index7 = 7;
                do
                {
                    if ((data.CO_CAL >> index7 & 1) != 0)
                    {
                        par[n_par1] = data.cos[index7];
                        ++n_par1;
                    }
                    else
                        data.cos[index7] = (double)coefficients[index7];
                    ++index7;
                }
                while (index7 <= 9);
                control.Initialize();
                //< Module >.lm_minimize(((Vector<CalPoint>)calPoints).Size, n_par1, par, (ILMCallbacks)callbacks, (lm_data_type)data, control);
                int index8 = 0;
                int index9 = 7;
                do
                {
                    if ((data.CO_CAL >> index9 & 1) != 0)
                    {
                        data.cos[index9] = par[index8];
                        ++index8;
                    }
                    ++index9;
                }
                while (index9 <= 9);
                int index10 = 0;
                do
                {
                    coefficients[index10] = (int)data.cos[index10];
                    ++index10;
                }
                while (index10 < 10);
                int coefficient = coefficients[6];
                if (coefficient < 0)
                {
                    if (coefficient < -8388607)
                    {
                        coefficients[6] = -8388607;
                        data.CO_CAL &= -65;
                        data.cos[6] = 0.0;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else if (coefficient > 536870911)
                {
                    coefficients[6] = 33554431;
                    data.CO_CAL &= -65;
                }
                else
                    break;
                ++num;
            }
            while (num < 2);
            if (coefficients[0] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 64;
            if (coefficients[7] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 128;
            if (coefficients[9] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 8;
            if (coefficients[4] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 2;
            if (coefficients[5] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 4;
            if (coefficients[3] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 16;
            if (coefficients[2] < 0)
                negCoeffs |= 32;
            return 0;

        }
```

But I have problems with a function and a class that is:

```
< Module >.lm_minimize(((Vector<CalPoint>)calPoints).Size, n_par1, par, (ILMCallbacks)callbacks, (lm_data_type)data, control);
```

I can't find the class  and I don't know what it refers to... it would be very useful if you can help me find a solution...

Thanks

Comment: Which decompiler are you using? I'd guess worst case you can do an export-all-sources and grep them for lm_minimize. I'd think most tools would let you double-click on lm_minimize and it'll take you to the definition though.

Comment: Yes i can check lm_minimize function but it has unreadable code (hexadecimal, binary, etc.) i used two decompilers.. JetBrains dotPeek and Telerik JustDecompile

Comment: Could you provide the dll? I would like to try it.